# How to tell the 'bottleneck' in a muti-pipe command

Tags: bash, pipe

Say i have a command using several pipes.
This could be any command but for example lets use this simple cut and sort.
e.g

```
cat data.tsv | cut -f1,5,8,12 | sort | uniq -c | sed -e "s/cat/dog/g" | sort -k1nr > output.tsv
```

How can i 'profile' this?

Is there anyway i can say that its the sed or the uniq that's slowing down my execution time?

In my ideal world i'd love to see something like:

```
1- cat: 15 lines per second
2- cut: 13 lines per second
3- sort: 6 lines per second
4- uniq: 6 lines per second (Limited by input)
5- sed: 6 lines per second (Limited by input)
6- sort 6 lines per second (Limited by input)
7- write 6 lines per second (Limited by input)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385408/get-program-execution-time-in-the-shell, hope this will help you to sort it out

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `pv` to count lines through a pipe. With pv you can step by step find the bottleneck.

```
cat data.tsv | pv -lr > /dev/null

cat data.tsv | cut -f1,5,8,12 | pv -lr > /dev/null

cat data.tsv | cut -f1,5,8,12 | sort | pv -lr > /dev/null

cat data.tsv | cut -f1,5,8,12 | sort | uniq -c | pv -lr > /dev/null

...
```

Example with pv‘s output:

```
timeout 10 yes | sed 's/yes/foo/' | rev | pv -lr >/dev/null
[ 120k/s]
```